# Error in realm when using stripe payment method

Tags: android, realm, stripe-payments

i am integrating "Strip" payment method in my app but when i add the stripe dependence    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:1.0.3' also try  compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+' an error occur that is 
[image]

i see many answer for realm Re-linker like using

compile 'com.getkeepsafe.relinker:relinker:1.2.1'
Compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0' but the problem is still exist 
this is my Realm application class

```
public class WifiExploreApplication extends Application {
@Override

public void onCreate(){
super.onCreate();

RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .name("com.holygon.zaingz.alu").build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration)
   }

}
```

this is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 'Google Apis:Google Apis:23'
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.wifiexplorer"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionName "1.0"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
productFlavors {
}
}
repositories {
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}  

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.github.sembozdemir:ViewPagerArrowIndicator:1.0.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0"
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'

compile 'com.getkeepsafe.relinker:relinker:1.2.1'
compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:1.0.3'

}


dependencies {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
 compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.0'

}



allprojects {
repositories {

    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
 }
}

apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

and

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all   sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.88.2"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
      jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

before using stripe all the things going well but when i use strip it will show error 
any suggestion will appreciate able..

Comment: Could you please try to use the latest Realm version?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the AAR Gradle Plugin version of Realm (as in 0.88.0+, but an outdated one, considering the latest is 1.1.0) but you're never actually calling `apply plugin: 'realm-android'` in your build.gradle file.

You're also missing this from your application class

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Oh by the way, you probably should use [modularized version of Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project) so that you wouldn't even need Multi-Dex in the first place.

Comment: There is actually `apply plugin: 'realm-android'` at the end of app's `build.gradle` :)

Comment: @beeender oh I missed that